# Trouble with Xpath in Google Spreadsheets (ImportXML)

Tags: html, xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is a great site, and I've already had a lot of questions answered simply by scrolling and searching through other postings. Unfortunately, I can't seem to track down an answer that specifically helps this problem, and figured I would try posting and looking for help-

I'm using ImportXML and google spreadsheets to 'scrape'a few product descriptions from a retail site. It's been working fine for the most part, and I have done it in 2 ways:

1) Specific call to the description part of a post:

```
=ImportXML(A1,"//div[@class='desc']")
```

2) Call to the entire 'product Card', which also returns info such as product title, price, time posted, and places these items in adjacent cells in my Google spreadsheet:

```
=ImportXML(A1,"//div[@class='productCard']")
```

Both have worked fine, but I've ran into a different problem using each method. If I can resolve even one of these problems, then I'll happily scrap the other method, I just need one of them to work. The problems are:

Method 1) The website prohibits sellers from including contact information in product postings-- when they include an email address anyways, the site automatically blocks it, so that in the posting it simply appears as "...you can reach me at [obscured]" or something like that. The [obscured] appears in a different colour text and is obviously treated differently somehow. When I scrape these descriptions using Method 1, ImportXML appears to get 'bumped' when it hits the word [obscured], and it passed the remaining text from that product description to the next cell over in my spreadsheet. This ruins the entire organization of the sheet, and I'd like to find a way where I can get ImportXML to just ignore the [obscured], and still place the entire text of the product description in one cell.

Method 2) My call for the entire 'product Card' is as follows:

```
=ImportXML(A1,"//div[@class='productCard']")
```

As mentioned, this works fine (for most products), and I don't mind the additional info (price, date, etc.) being posted in adjacent cells.
However, the website also allows certain products to be 'featured', where they appear in a different colour box on the site, and are therefore more likely to get a buyer's attention.
Using this method, the 'featured' products are not scraped or imported into my spreadsheet, but are simply passed over.

The source code (on actual site) (via 'inspect element' in Safari) for both the description (Method 1) and product card (Method 2) look as follows (for a normal product (a) and a featured product (b)):

(a)

```
<div id="productSearchResults">
<div class="productCard tracked">
<div>...</div>
<div class="stats">...</div>
<div class="desc collapsed descFull">...</div>
</div>
```

(b)

```
<div id="productSearchResults">
<div class="productCard featured tracked">
<div>...</div>
<div class="stats">...</div>
<div class="desc collapsed descFull">...</div>
</div>
```

You can see in both (a) an (b) the 'desc' class that I call in Method 1, which seems to work fine.
From my reading on this site, I think I've learned that a given class can't have more than one word, and therefore the use of "desc collapsed descFull" and "productCard tracked" and "productCard featured tracked" don't represent classes with 3, 2 and 3 words in the title, but instead cases where multiple classes have been assigned?

Regardless, the call to 'desc' (Method 1) works fine and seems to get all descriptions.
In method 2 therefore, I would have thought that a call to 'productCard' would get the info for all products, both featured and regular, as 'featured' is an extra class assigned to some 'productCard's. If I call all 'productCard's, shouldn't the normal AND featured ones be returned? This is currently not the case. I've tried calling just 'tracked' and just 'featured' as classes, and neither returns anything, so my logic that they are their own class equivalent to 'productCard' may be flawed.

In summary, the 'desc' call in Method 1 works fine, and even gets descriptions for 'featured' products. However, when contact information is included in the description and is displayed as [obscured] it bumps my data into the next cell in the spreadsheet, immediately following the word. This throws off and ruins all organization.

In Method 2, I am not getting the featured products at all, which greatly weakens what I am trying to do. Can either (or both!) of these problems be fixed??

Thanks so so much for any help you can give me.

***UPDATE: As seen in the comments below, use of the 'contain' as suggested improved Method 2 by retrieving both regular and featured products. However, featured product cards have extra text elements, and since the entire card is being scraped in this method, featured products do not match the cell alignment that regular products do. If there is a way to fix Method 1, this would therefore be much better.
As outlined in the comments below, the [obscured] text appears in a 'span' that follows underneath/indented from the

```
<div class="desc descFull collapsed"
```

as

```
<span class="obscureText">[obscured]</span>
```

Is there any way that I can import the 'desc's as I have been, but tell the XPath to essentially 'ignore' the [obscured] span, or at least deal with it in a way that doesn't make description text immediately after [obscured] appear one cell over?

Thanks so much everyone!

Comment: It seems that your XPath parser is not very strict because `//div[@class='desc']` does *not* match `<div class="desc collapsed descFull">`. You would need to use `//div[contains(@class,'desc')]` to match it. XPath does not understand what a `class` is. It reads `@class` as an attribute, so if the contents are different, it does not match. Try your expressions here: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html Do they give different results?

Comment: Thanks for your response Held, out of interest I tried the use of 'contains' before @class,'productCard' in Method 2, and it now pulls both regular AND featured products for me, so that's a step in the right direction!
I hear what you are saying about the parser not being very strict, and am trying to experiment with the testing site you provided. I'm a pretty big newbie though so I'm not sure yet what to report.

Comment: Some additional info I can now provide in regards to the original posting:
-The [obscured] text I wish to avoid (or at least prevent from bumping remaining text to the next cell in my spreadsheet) appears in the source code (inspect element on site in Safari) as:

    <span class="obscureText">[obscured]</span>

Within/below the 

    <div class="desc descFull expanded"

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap your function with the `concatenate()`-function to make sure it all shows up in one cell:

```
=concatenate(ImportXML(A1,"//div[@class='productCard']"))
```